# Trojan downloaded

Tags: security, antivirus, virus

Not sure this is the best place to ask but I'll give it a shot...

My son clicked a link in a spam message on my phone which downloaded
Android/trojan.downloader.agent

Instantly kaspersky and malwarebytes spotted the trojan and quarantined

My question is...
Should this mean that the virus has been adequately dealt with or is there a chance that it may still remain on the system?

Comment: The virus has been dealt with.